# Chrony does not want to synchronize

Tags: linux, ntp, chrony

I am trying to deploy an ntp server in my local network, so I followed these steps (i used the tutorial [here](https://docs.openstack.org/newton/install-guide-ubuntu/environment-ntp-controller.html)):

`apt install chrony`

And I added the following lines:

`server time.google.com iburst
allow 0/0`

Then I made a :

`service chrony restart`

I am suposed to have an output like this:

```
# chronyc sources

  210 Number of sources = 2
  MS Name/IP address         Stratum Poll Reach LastRx Last sample
  ==========================================================================
  ^* 192.0.2.12                    2   6   177    46    +17us[  -23us] +/-   68ms
```

And this is my output:

```
# chronyc sources
210 Number of sources = 1
MS Name/IP address         Stratum Poll Reach LastRx Last sample               
==========================================================================
^? time3.google.com           0   8     0     -     +0ns[   +0ns] +/-    0ns
```

As you can see the `+0ns[   +0ns] +/-    0ns` do not change and the clock does not synchronise with the google server -- where is the problem ?

Comment: `? indicates sources to which connectivity has been lost or whose packets don’t pass all tests` - are you sure you can get time service through your network to time3.google.com?

Comment: Yes, when i install my OS i usually manually choose my NTP server, but as you said it might be blocked by my company firewall i will check this out and give you the answer

Comment: did you learn whether the firewall was blocking NTP service?

Comment: Yeah i did and the port was open , i also found that when i have ^? next to the namle of the server instead of * it's not the default one , maybe that's the problem ?

Comment: The basic problem is the value of `0` for "Reach" (no valid responses received).